# Motivation for separated and proper schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves, schemes

Hartshorne mention at the beginning of section 4 in chapter 2 that the definition of separated is similliar to hausdorff. We all can see that. That is also what I found in google. Again - we all can see that so i dont find it helpfull enough. I guess that one can truly understand the "true nature" of the definition after working enough with schemes, but I still have a feeling that maybe I am missing something since separation appears, for example, when defining curves, etc.. Why is it so important for us? What will we get, for example, if we drop the separation axiom? Where the separation takes its part when defining curves for "actually being curves" as we would like them to behave?

Comment: If you try to get things that have ''doubled points'' (like the line with a doubled origin), you generically leave the world of separated schemes. In this way the separated property largely tells you that your points lie ''far enough away,'' i.e., there aren't really schematically indistinguishable points.

Comment: As for the motivation for properness, this is roughly equivalent to the definition of proper maps in complex analysis. Essentially, you want the preimage of a compact subspace to be again compact. Think of a proper map as some sort of near-finiteness or size-restriction type property. Things may be big, but they aren't too big to get a handle on in some bounded way.